# Ошибка Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Tags: mysqli, php

Имеется такая простенькая функция

```
function smiles($t)
{
$querysmiles = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `smiles` ORDER BY `id` ASC"); 
while($rowsmiles = mysqli_fetch_array($querysmiles))
{
$code[] = $rowsmiles['code'];
$smile_url[] = '<img src="'.$home.'/system/smiles/'.$rowsmiles['smile_url'].'" alt="smile" title="'.$rowsmiles['smile_url'].'" />'; 
}
$t = str_replace($code, $smile_url, $t);
return $t; 
}
```

При ее использовании возникает ошибка Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in

Ругается на строчку

```
 $querysmiles = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `smiles` ORDER BY `id` ASC");
```

По идее там все правильно.

Answer (score 3):

В общем решил проблему тем, что в функцию добавил global $mysqli;

Comment: Почитайте про IoC.

Answer (score 0):

если использовать mysqli, то лучше просто mysqli_query

Comment: Так кстати вообще не работает.

Comment: Как оно может не работать, если существуют два варианта:

Объектно-ориентированный стиль и Процедурный стиль.
http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php

Comment: чем лучше то ?

Comment: возиться не надо. Вы что-то добавили, для того, чтобы это работало. Процедурный стиль этого не требует. Он прост, позволяет обходиться без объектов.

Comment: @Arc я ничего не добавлял :)

Comment: В общем решил проблему тем, что в функцию добавил global $mysqli;
Цитата Вашего ответа

Comment: @Arc и ответ не мой :P